# ui is undefined jsf primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, undefined

I have a problem with using primefaces autocomplete component. When triggered ia get the error $ui. is undefinded and the backing bean is not even called.

My code is:

```
<p:autoComplete completeMethod="#{auto.uliList}" value="#{naroc.ulValue}"></p:autoComplete>
```

Big thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

This is recognizeable as a jQuery / jQuery UI conflict.

PrimeFaces ships with jQuery and jQuery UI libraries by itself already. If you have manually included jQuery and/or jQuery UI by a custom `<script>` or `<h:outputScript>`, then it would only conflict with PrimeFaces-provided ones and result in this kind of "foo is undefined" errors. You should **remove** your manually included jQuery scripts from the page (and your webapp) and rely on PrimeFaces-provided ones instead.

If you have pages which don't necessarily use PrimeFaces components (and thus its bundled jQuery scripts won't necessarily be auto-included on every page), then you need to explicitly specify PrimeFaces own jQuery instead:

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />
```

Comment: Still not working. I have to mention that i'm using liferay with several portlets, so the jquery is implemented only on one project, and can be used on all. Interesting that using richfaces doesn't even come to this error just don't work... hm..

Comment: Liferay is beyond me. The problem is at least in JavaScript context. You've got to investigate which JS files are exactly been served and downloaded (just press F12 in Chrome/IE9/Firebug to see them all) and then naildown the JS conflicts (duplicate namespaces, etc). RichFaces also ships with jQuery bundled by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to resolve my problem.
it was quite simple but effective. So if you come up with a prolem similar to mine just add this code to your page head:

```
<h:outputScript target="head">
    jQuery.noConflict();
</h:outputScript>
```

Comment: This confirms my answer. Your "solution" is however more a workaround/hack than a real solution.